# npm - "Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable."

Tags: python, node.js, npm, npm-install

I'm trying to run the following command: `npm install -g bower gulp cordova ionic tsd@next karma-cli protractor node-gyp coffee-script js-beautify typescript npm-check`

I have installed Python, Visual Studio Express and node-gyp so thought I'd be good to go, however I get the following errors:

[image]

Regarding the `"Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable."` error, I'm a little confused because I have set the PYTHON environmental variable like so:

[image]

Any ideas please?

Comment: Is there an underscore in your actual path?

Comment: Thanks @PadraicCunningham, yes there is http://i.imgur.com/1kuv8Pw.png

Comment: Can you post the full evn exactly as you have it set? You can also add it to your PATH

Comment: Thanks, I've set it to `C:\Program Files\Python_2.7.10\python.exe`

Comment: Set it to your folder with the executable, `C:\Program Files\Python_2.7.10` or add   to your PATH http://stackoverflow.com/a/4855685/2141635 under system variables

Comment: Ah! That makes sense, thank you very much. Still getting the same error though unfortunately, even with it set to `C:\Program Files\Python_2.7.10`

Comment: no prob, you're welcome. You can add and accept an answer that worked for you

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You got to add python to your PATH variable. One thing you can do is Edit your Path variable now and add

`;%PYTHON%;`

Your variable PYTHON should point to the root directory of your python installation.

Comment: Thank you, I've set the PYTHON path to `C:\Program Files\Python_2.7.10;%PYTHON%;` but I'm still getting the same error unfortunately

Comment: Actually you want to set your python path to `C:\Program Files\Python_2.7.10` and then edit your `PATH` Variable and add `;%PYTHON;` . I've looked it up locally and i added `C:\Python34;C:\Python34\Scripts;` to get things working. Although as you see im not using Python 2.

Comment: Actually this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21433154/3378288 describes exactly what i was trying to explain but in a more detailed way ;). For you to note: it's not important if your path variable is `PY_HOME`, or `PYTHON`. It's just important that it matches with what you insert in your path variable.

Comment: Thank you very much, I've set the PYTHON variable properly now and added it into PATH, but still getting the same error... will take a look at the link you posted now :) Cheers

Comment: omg... I didn't realise I had to close the command window for the new variables to be in play. Thank you all so much for the replies and advice!

Comment: Installing Python2.7.10 and setting the PATH and PYTHON environment variables successfully resolved the issue. Thanks you @jvecsei

Answer (score 128):

Try:

Install all the required tools and configurations using Microsoft's windows-build-tools by running `npm install -g windows-build-tools` from an elevated *PowerShell* (run as Administrator).

https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#environment-setup-and-configuration

Comment: This did the trick on my behalf. Pretty annoying though that it will install Python 2.7 as I don't want to soil my environment with a Python version that I'm not going to use.

Comment: It should be the perfect answer.

Comment: Fixed this error, and probably others I haven't hit yet. Going into the list of dev machine setup steps!

Comment: is system restart required after that? it appears yes for me to get work

Comment: FYI - that command will reboot your machine during install

Comment: the command currently returns this response "windows-build-tools@5.2.2: Node.js now includes build tools for Windows. You probably no longer need this tool. See https://github.com/felixrieseberg/windows-build-tools for details."

Comment: windows-build-tools is not deprecated.

Answer (score 47):

https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#on-windows

https://github.com/Microsoft/nodejs-guidelines/blob/master/windows-environment.md#environment-setup-and-configuration

try

```
npm config set python D:\Library\Python\Python27\python.exe
```

Comment: This resulted in npm ERR! `python` is not a valid npm option

Comment: the 'python' option was removed with npm v9 - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74522956/python-is-not-a-valid-npm-option.

Answer (score 39):

I installed python2.7 to solve this issue.

Comment: This fixed my issue...sadly.

Comment: @ZhangBuzz It's because the gyp tool that node-gyp depends on was written for Python 2 and is not compatible with Python 3.

Comment: 2021 here, they still want it aaand the 2.7 cannot be installed due to bug (endless cycle).

Comment: and now 2022 here!

Comment: A note to all these complainers: that's not how software development works at all. Just because a new year started, it doesn't mean that developers go back and rewrite all their software to the latest language versions.

Comment: @LachoTomov get out of the waterfall cycle its agile world, patches and version upgrades are required for fixing bugs and exploits or loose your bitcoin wallets to hippies

Comment: @MDT I'm well aware of what purpose patches and bug fixes serve, but there's so much more to that than most complaining junior devs here realize. For ex. there's this thing called "minor" and "major" releases - bug fixes usually go into "minor" and that's what you need to upgrade. Python 2.7 to 3 is a major release - and that's a completely different thing.

Answer (score 25):

> Just run below command with admin access

`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`

Comment: The package `windows-build0tools` is deprecated: https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools

Comment: It shows me "Downloading installers failed. Error: TypeError: 'process.env' only accepts a configurable, writable, and enumerable data descriptor" using npm v9.6.7 with Node.js v18.17.1

Answer (score 12):

The easiest way is to let NPM do everything for you,

```
npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global windows-build-tools
```

Comment: Don't think this is merged in yet, and it didn't work on this end - https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/pull/1109

Answer (score 11):

MAC: In my case, I just run the below command and the error resolved:

```
npm config set python python3
```

Comment: This one introduce more errors like ` Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print`

Comment: `npm ERR! `python` is not a valid npm option`

Answer (score 9):

I have recently encountered this issue in a dockerfile using `node:16-alpine` as base image. I have added following run command to fix the issue:

```
FROM node:alpine as build-stage
RUN apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip make g++
```

Here, both tags `node:alpine` & `node:16-alpine` are same.

Comment: add `RUN apk add --no-cache python3 py3-pip make g++` to docker file solved my issue, thnx!

Answer (score 8):

My Problem was the usage of Node v16.

I went back to Node v12 (v14 is probably fine as well) and it worked.

Comment: Any idea why this fixes it? Does it not use python?

Answer (score 5):

One of the following solutions will work for you:

1. npm config set python `c:\Python\27\python.exe` or `set PYTHON=D:\Python\bin\Python.exe`
2. `npm config set python D:\Library\Python\Python27\python.exe`
3. Let npm configure everything for you (takes forever to complete) `npm --add-python-to-path='true' --debug install --global windows-build-tools` (Must be executed via "Run As Administrator" PowerShell)

If not... Try to install the required package on your own (I did so, and it was `node-sass`, after installing it manually, the whole `npm install` was successfully completed

Comment: First installing node-sass manually actually worked for me. Had been struggling with python thing.

Answer (score 4):

You are running the Command Prompt as an admin. You have only defined PYTHON for your user. You need to define it in the bottom "System variables" section.

Also, you should only point the variable to the folder, not directly to the executable.

Comment: Thank you, I've added `C:\Program Files\Python_2.7.10;%PYTHON%;` in as the PYTHON variable under System variables and unfortunately am still getting the same error :(

Comment: As mentioned in the other comments, `%PYTHON%` should go in the PATH variable, not PYTHON. By adding it in PYTHON, you are making a circular reference, which is not good for your computer.

Comment: Thank you, have just changed PYTHON and included it in the PATH variable and *still* getting the same error. Argh :(

Answer (score 3):

Had this issue on `node:18` alpine docker image on Apple Silicon where only `python3` is available but at least some versions of `node-gyp` [don't support `pyhton3` yet](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp/issues/1268#issuecomment-323550728). So I had to use an alpine version that still had `python2`:

```
FROM node:18.8.0-alpine3.15

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk --no-cache add python2 make g++

COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn

COPY . .
```

Answer (score 2):

```
delete node_modules 
delete packagelock.json and yarn.lock(if have)
npm cache clean --force
npm install
```

Answer (score 1):

Run : npm --vs2015 install --global windows-build-tools

Comment: perfect answer since this fixes the missing python2.7 issue too

Answer (score 1):

```
npm config set python D:\Library\Python\Python27\python.exe
```

This kind off worked for me from Tom Gao's answer

Make sure to change in npmrc file as it doesnt automatically takes \ for the path
and do add Python in env var also as mentioned in the answers.

Answer (score 0):

use node version which mentioned in package.json.

using nvm (node version manager) you can switch between respective node version mentions in package.json

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32076783)

Answer (score 0):

as mentionned by jvecsei

For me adding D:\Softwares\Python\2.7\Scripts instead of D:\Softwares\Python\2.7 to PATH worked.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33091252)

Answer (score 0):

npm config set python $(which python)

Answer (score 0):

On macOS installing Python 2 solves this:

With asdf, in a .tool-versions file:

```
python 2.7.18
```

Then

```
asdf plugin add python
asdf install
```