# Error while trying to install node-jasper

Tags: javascript, node.js

[image: Error Image]

it shows error as python.exe not founded but i have installed python and added into environmental variable and also i've tried by node version 8,10,12 but it not working
i tried to install node-jasper with help this link
https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jasper  but it throws same error

can any one help me resolve this issue?

thanks in advance

Comment: check your setting of env variable: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372618/npm-cant-find-python-executable-python-you-can-set-the-python-env-variabl

Comment: Welcome to SO! Make sure to check out the [how to ask page.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Try not to post screenshots of error messages. Instead, it would be better to copy and paste the text into the question.

Answer (score 0):

I still had that error, what I did was install python as I saw on this site http://www.frlp.utn.edu.ar/materias/sintaxis/tutorialinstalarPython3.pdf,
but change the installation folder to C:\Python\Python311. Then add that path and C:\Python\Python311\Scripts to the System Path and User Path.

I reinstalled but I got the error You need to install the latest version of Visual Studio and I solved it with
npm i -g windows-build-tools

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33644203)