# I'm setting up an ionic project and getting these errors when run the command npm install

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, node-gyp

```
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:484:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:509:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:149:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.18362
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\npm-lifecycle\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd E:\test-proj\Angular\ionic-test\node_modules\ed25519
gyp ERR! node -v v10.0.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is about python, not node or angular. There are a lot of questions about python path problem like:

[npm - "Can't find Python executable "python", you can set the PYTHON env variable."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34372618/npm-cant-find-python-executable-python-you-can-set-the-python-env-variabl)

https://github.com/iost-official/explorer/issues/1

https://hisk.io/how-to-fix-node-js-gyp-err-cant-find-python-executable-python-on-windows/

Answer (score 0):

I installed windows build tools and it solved my problem.