# Can't able to install rudderstack in machine

Tags: python, npm, etl, npm-install, rudderstack-sdk

Hi all I was trying to install rudderstack in developer machine by following there docs.
while installing the dependencies using `npm i` I am getting this error-

```
 npm i

> heapdump@0.3.15 install C:\Users\admin\Desktop\RudderStack\rudder-server\rudder-transformer\node_modules\heapdump
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\admin\Desktop\RudderStack\rudder-server\rudder-transformer\node_modules\heapdump>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from command line or npm configuration
gyp ERR! find Python Python is not set from environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python2" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python2" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if "python3" can be used
gyp ERR! find Python - "python3" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if the py launcher can be used to find Python 2
gyp ERR! find Python - "py.exe" is not in PATH or produced an error
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python27\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python27\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python checking if Python is C:\Python37\python.exe
gyp ERR! find Python - "C:\Python37\python.exe" could not be run
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python You need to install the latest version of Python.
gyp ERR! find Python Node-gyp should be able to find and use Python. If not,
gyp ERR! find Python you can try one of the following options:
gyp ERR! find Python - Use the switch --python="C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python   (accepted by both node-gyp and npm)
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the environment variable PYTHON
gyp ERR! find Python - Set the npm configuration variable python:
gyp ERR! find Python   npm config set python "C:\Path\To\python.exe"
gyp ERR! find Python For more information consult the documentation at:
gyp ERR! find Python https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp#installation
gyp ERR! find Python **********************************************************
gyp ERR! find Python
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Could not find any Python installation to use
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.fail (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:307:47)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.runChecks (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:136:21)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:225:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.execFileCallback (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\find-python.js:271:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at exithandler (child_process.js:326:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.errorhandler (child_process.js:338:5)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:275:12)
gyp ERR! stack     at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:467:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:82:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.19041
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\admin\Desktop\RudderStack\rudder-server\rudder-transformer\node_modules\heapdump
gyp ERR! node -v v14.17.1
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v5.1.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^6.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-react@^7.20.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@18.2.0 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-react-hooks@^4 || ^3 || ^2.3.0 || ^1.7.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN The package minimist is included as both a dev and production dependency.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.1.3 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.1.3: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! heapdump@0.3.15 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the heapdump@0.3.15 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-10-08T09_58_23_431Z-debug.log
```

I have already installed python on my system and configured it as well. also tried npm cache clean, nothing worked anyone can suggest me how to fix this issue ?
Please help

Comment: Do you have the Python installation folder in your PATH environment variable?

Comment: yes its set in path as well as i made a new env var and called it inside path like- %Python% in cmd also while typing python --version its giving me the version "Python 3.10.0"  so I think its working ?

Comment: @Amara. You might want to install the tools required for installing native modules. Similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48516179

Comment: In case someone wants to install using Docker/docker-compose. This link may be helpful. https://rojuka.com/p/posts/best-top-3-open-source-segment-alternative-actually-you-don-t-know-the-3rd-one-1#self-hosting-rudderstack-and-complete-docker-composeyml-for-you