# python is not a valid npm option

Tags: npm, npm-config

I am trying to set an older version of python in order to install modules and build an old node project.

I run this command:

```
npm config set python=python2.7
```

OR

```
npm config set python C:\Python27\python.exe
```

In both cases I am getting this error:

```
npm ERR! `python` is not a valid npm option
```

Nove v16.14.2

Npm v9.1.2

Comment: I faced the same problem trying to set `user` option, that worked with 8.14

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Consider downgrading npm to v8 for now:

```bash
npm install -g npm@^8
```

Alternatively, just run:

```bash
npm config edit
```

and add:

```
python=C:\Python27\python.exe
```

in a new line.

Comment: I didn't need to downgrade npm, but editing the config directly helped solve my issue indeed. Still curious why npm config set didn't work though. Thanks!

Comment: On my Mac I needed to add following to the config: python=/usr/bin/python3

Answer (score -1):

Update your npm

```
npm install -g npm@^8
```

Retry the command

```
npm config set python C:\Python27\python.exe
```

Answer (score -3):

Consider running fix command:

```
npm config fix
```

In my case, it resolved the issue